# Cast(Of ?) from UIElement

Tags: vb.net, linq, silverlight, uielement

In silverlight my custom controls are in the`UIElementCollection` of my `StackPanel`. I want to get a list of them by a specific value. There only `DivElements` in the container. It returns `Nothing` when I know I have one or more. I know I can make a simple loop and cast types inline, but I want to get better with `LINQ` and `Cast(Of TResult)`. My attempt at casting:

```
Dim myList = TryCast(spDivs.Children.Where(Function(o) DirectCast(o, DivElement).ElementParent Is bComm).Cast(Of DivElement)(), List(Of DivElement))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you can't *cast* into a `List(Of DivElement)`.  The collection is a `UIElementCollection`, not a `List(Of T)`.

You could build a new list, though.  This can also be simplified by using `OfType` instead of casting manually:

```
Dim myList = spDivs.Children.OfType(Of DivElement)()
                            .Where(Function(o) o.ElementParent Is bComm)
                            .ToList()
```

Comment: I totally missed the `OfType`.